# JBOSS 7 jndi ejb call on JBOSS 6 or vice versa

Tags: jboss7.x, jndi

As part of the migration process from JBOSS 6 to 7 there will still be many EJB running on JBOSS 6.

Is there a way to make JNDI call from JBOSS 7 container to some EJB in JBOSS 6 (or vice versa)

I know that the jndi name and the procedure to call in 7 is different. But how can I put the jboss related jndi jars of 6 and 7 together without creating conflicts.

So the question is: Is remote ejb jndi lookup from AS7 to AS6 possible at all by any means. Can AS7 co-exist with AS6 ?

The closest answer that I got was the following:
http://jboss-as7-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/Invoking-remote-EJBs-on-JBoss-AS-4-5-6-from-JBoss-AS-7-td5710379.html